# How to delete CartEntries from hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to create a CronJob that deletes Cart Entries of a specific type. I have allready found all entries with the needed PK, but I still cant delete them.

I found on the web that I cant use the FlexibleSearchQuery for that. Also I did not found any method for that in the CartEntryService. Where is the delete logic?

Comment: https://help.sap.com/viewer/9d346683b0084da2938be8a285c0c27a/1905/en-US/8c3a6caf866910148cd58d649958d7e2.html This didn't help ?

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary Not really. Because I do not need to purify and delete the Cart. I need to delete only a specific type of CartEntries from All carts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `modelService` to remove any model from the database. In your case, all you need to do is pass list of **cartEntryModel** to `getModelService().removeAll(list)`

Look at the **DefaultCartService** **updateQuantities** method, basically this method is invoked with 0 quantity for the cart entry which the user tries to remove from the cart.

```
    final Collection<CartEntryModel> toRemove = new LinkedList<CartEntryModel>();
    final Collection<CartEntryModel> toSave = new LinkedList<CartEntryModel>();
    for (final Map.Entry<CartEntryModel, Long> e : getEntryQuantityMap(cart, quantities).entrySet())
    {
        final CartEntryModel cartEntry = e.getKey();
        final Long quantity = e.getValue();
        if (quantity == null || quantity.longValue() < 1)
        {
            toRemove.add(cartEntry);
        }
        else
        {
            cartEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
            toSave.add(cartEntry);
        }
    }
    getModelService().removeAll(toRemove);
```

You can achieve the same form using a groovy script. Refer [create a Cronjob using Groovy script in SAP Hybris](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/07/cronjob-using-groovy-script-hybris.html)

**Groovy Script example:**

```
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService;
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.user.CartEntryModel;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult;
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;



def removeCartEntries()

 {
  final SearchResult<CartEntryModel> searchResults = flexibleSearchService.search("query to get the list of cartentries")
  if (searchResults != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(searchResults.getResult())) {
      modelService.removeAll(searchResults.getResult());
   }
 }
removeCartEntries();

println "done";
```